# How to overlay a youtube video over your website

Tags: javascript, css, html, youtube

Hello I am trying to figure out how to do the follow

1.Click an image on a page

2.This will overlay a youtube video on top of your current page

3.Clicking any transparent part of the screen will return user back to said page

I have added a screenshot to help illustrate my scenario.
Thank you for the help in advance, this is for a side project I am working on!!
I guess I need more reputation before attaching an image so I have added a jing screenshot. http://screencast.com/t/ceBkx8K1Cy7

Comment: Try out: [VideoBox-Lightbox](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty simple method that I think does what you require without needing a plugin.  You can play around with the video size and location, but the logic won't change.  When the video is displayed, clicking on the 'TEST' button won't trigger the default event (and alert) - rather, is is the same as the entire area outside the video.  Once the video is hidden, the TEST link will work correctly.  Please use the 'full screen' option when running the snippet.

If you want to stop the video playing when you hide the div, you need to load the iframe dynamically as part of the button click function, and then set the div html to `''` when hiding it.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#video, #overlay').fadeIn('slow');
  $('#video-container').html('<iframe width=560 height=315 src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/OMOga8x6aLk frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});

$(document).on('touchend, mouseup', function(e) {
  if (!$('#video').is(e.target)) {
    $('#video, #overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#video-container').html('');
  }
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
  alert('video is not visible');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #888888;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}
#video {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="btn2">TEST</button>

  <div id="overlay"></div>

  <div id="video">
    <div id="video-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: For some reason the Youtube video won't play in the SO sandbox, and I don't have time now to figure out why.  Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hr99tzju/1/) where it's fine (same code).

EDIT 2: Updated code to provide for responsive size/position for video container.

EDIT 3:  Added support for `touchend` event.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect response. I have three minor problem.
1) Is there a way to make the video auto center instead of left:30px because when I change video size it is no longer center.
2) Can I make the video automatically scale with the browser. This way if you open it on a tablet or phone it wont be overwhelmingly large.
3) Maybe its my tester mindset but if you launch the video quickly and then begin to scroll the overlay sometimes get goofy.

If you would like to see my progress check out fitgen.myshopify.com / tohewd . Your suggestion is right below the slideshow. Feel free to watch!

Comment: Any way to make touch more responsive on mobile devices? I cannot seem to get the overlay to go away on my ipad. Possibly "$(document).mouseup(function(e)" can be replaced with a more universal method?

Comment: Code edited above.  I don't have a touch device here to test, but it should work.  :)